# SQL - counting by id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently trying to list the number of visits attended by each vet. I have to include the vets name details with the count of visits attended. I then have to sort the report by the vets title.

Visit table structure:

```
visit_id, vet_id, pet_id, Visit_Date, Basic_Cost, Symptom, Treatment
```

Vet table structure:

```
vet_id, Surname, Forename, Title, Ext_Number, Position, Salary
```

Below is my initial SQL command that I have created. It doesn't work and I was wondering how to create an SQL command for the above question. All help is appreciated and please note I'm using ms access.

```
SELECT vet_id, Title, Forename, Surname, COUNT(vet_id)
FROM visit, vet
ORDER BY Title;
```

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause in there...

Comment: and you need to join visit to vet based on Vet_ID

Comment: Do you want to `cross join` data?

Comment: How would I join visit and vet by vet_id?

Comment: *It doesn't work* is an absolutely meaningless problem description. In what way does it *not work*? Does it return the wrong data? Do you get an error message? If you want help here, you need to clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve, the difficulty you're having to do so, provide the **relevant details**, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT vet_id, title, Forename, Surname,
 (SELECT COUNT(visit.vet_id) FROM visit WHERE visit.vet_id = vet.vet_id) AS visits
FROM vet
ORDER BY vet.vet_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want all vets even if they haven't had visits...

```
SELECT P.vet_id, Title, Forename, Surname, coalesce(COUNT(V.vet_id),0) as VetVisitCount
FROM VET P
LEFT JOIN  Visit V
 on P.Vet_ID = V.Vet_ID
GROUP BY P.vet_id, Title, Forename, Surname
ORDER BY Title;
```

Comment: I get an error saying vet_id could refer to more than one field from my FROM clause.

Comment: `vet_id` in the `GROUP BY` needs to be table/alias qualified. `GROUP BY P.vet_id`

Comment: Updated to account for the 2 missing alias on vet_Id (in select and in group by)

Comment: Thanks. Works great :)

Answer (score -1):

You need a GROUP BY

```
SELECT vet_id, Title, Forename, Surname, COUNT(vet_id)
FROM visit, vet
GROUP BY vet_id, Title, Forename, Surname
ORDER BY Title;
```

Comment: Although the GROUP BY was missing the JOIN was not correct either. This will not produce the desired result.